# Is it possible to use the old school page transition metatags?

Tags: html

Is it possible to use the old school HTML page transitions?

Unfortunately, I can't find them anymore as only CSS transitions come up.

In the past, you were able to add meta tags to your page that would add transitions between pages.

For example,

```
<meta transition="dissolve"/>
```

**Update:**

Found this http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/pagetransitions.php

Answer (score 1):

Wow, haven't seen this in a long time!  Good find.

Unfortunately, this isn't going to be possible in the old way as the whole page context is torn down between pages.  That is, one page can't transition to another because they're completely independent and don't really exist at the same time.

You could implement this yourself though if you did all of your page loading client-side.  You would need to use XHR or Fetch to get the next page, insert it into the DOM, then use CSS or JavaScript to actually do the transition.  [jQuery Mobile](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html) does this.  I suspect other frameworks do as well.

Comment: Right. It's up to the browser to implement. They would have to screenshot, load the next page, screenshot that and then create the transition. I guess if both pages had transitions set which one would win? If the page had it's own CSS transitions would they win? I do like how simple they were and if you used them on your own domain I don't see the problem. Only Internet Explorer had them I think.